# Magento2 : How to get all thge fields of a system.xml section / group

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I have created a module with custom system config entries :

Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
     <system>
         <tab id="mainconfig" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
             <label>Mine Special</label>
         </tab>
         <section id="fooconfig" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
             <class>separator-top</class>
             <label>FOO Configuration</label>
             <tab>mainconfig</tab>
             <resource>Vendor_Module::fooconfig_configuration</resource>

            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Emails Configuration</label>
                <field id="foo_mail" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>FOO Email</label>
                    <validate>required-entry validate-email</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="bar_mail" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="12" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>BAR Email</label>
                    <validate>required-entry validate-email</validate>
                </field>
            </group> 
         </section>
     </system>
 </config>
```

I now would like to be able to get all the fields of a section group, something like :

```
$Fields = $this->_scopeConfig->getFields('fooconfig/general',...);
foreach ($Fields as $Field) {
    $Entries = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('fooconfig/general/'.$Field->getId(), \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

//do what needed here
}
```

Is there a possibility to do somehting like that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is no method for getting fields like getFields().

You can get all values of a group at once like following way:

```
$fieldsArray  = array('fooconfig/general/foo_mail','fooconfig/general/bar_mail');

foreach($fieldsArray as $field){
    $entries = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($field, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    //do your action
}
```

Hope, by this way you can get your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to the show, but here's the answer anyway.

To get all the fields of a group you just need to call `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::getValue` and pass the `section_name/group_name` as the path (do not pass the field id).

So in your case, you need to

```
$fields = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('fooconfig/general');
foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
    // do what is needed here
    // Also notice that the getValue returns 
    // the field and value as a key-value pair 
    // when you call it like this
}
```